# Why does core uses the lib directory instead of the src one, for its classes?

Tags: 8

[Drupal 8 now uses the PSR-4 specification](https://www.drupal.org/node/2156625) for namespaces and auto-loading; module developers need to keep their PHP classes in their module's src directory.
However, if you look in the core directory, Drupal keeps all these in the lib directory.

Why is this so?

Comment: I was wandering that myself. My guess was that it is a leftover from the psr-1 days.

Answer (score 1):

The following [document](https://www.sitepoint.com/battle-autoloaders-psr-0-vs-psr-4/) explains the differences between PSR-4 and PSR-0, and the reason why PSR-4 was suggested.

It also explains that PSR-4 complies with the PSR-0.

Basically, when working with packages (modules) PSR-4 is preferable.
But the base package can still use PSR-0 and be readable.